# carregar .txt do armazenamento interno em um array

Tags: java, android

estou fazendo um app de contagem de estoque e ele precisa importar um txt e exportar o mesmo com as quantidades lidas na contagem, o problema é que pesquisando achei a biblioteca do android studio pra carregar o arquivo do armazenamento:

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    /**
     * Fires an intent to spin up the "file chooser" UI and select an image.
     */
    public void performFileSearch() {

        // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
        // browser.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

        // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
        // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
        // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
        // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
        // it would be "*/*".
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
```

na `onActivityResult` esta assim

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null){
        String barcode = result.getContents();
        if (barcode != null && !"".equals(barcode)){
            createFragment.setBarCode(barcode);
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
    // READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
    // response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i("resultado", "Uri: " + uri.toString());

            File file= new File(uri.getPath());
            String conteudoArquivo = file.getName();
            salvarArquivo(conteudoArquivo);
        }
    }
}
```

eu estou tentando carregar o arquivo txt em um array que é carregado na tela inicial, ja tentei de varias formas e nao consegui. Ao clicar no botao ele abre o armazenamento e consigo procurar e carregar o txt na  variavel uri depois disso nao consigo ler o arquivo e carregar no Array

Comment: Qual o local que está armazenado o txt? Eu recentemente criei uma biblioteca que trata os uri recebidos por meio do result. [HandlePathOz](https://github.com/onimur/handle-path-oz), caso tenha interesse de utilizá-la. A saída dos métodos que criei retornam a string do caminho real do arquivo, com ela é possível acessar o arquivo desejado. Dentro do repositório tem também exemplos da utilização da biblioteca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível pegar o conteúdo do arquivo diretamente pelo objeto File, para isso use a classe útil java.nio.file.Files

```
String conteudoArquivo = Files.readString(uri.getPath());
```